# Create dynamic query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB that store test results based on versions.
the DB get update daily, and u want to make my query dynamic according the version the db has.

```
SELECT
  test,
  MAX(CASE WHEN version = 'ABC' THEN throughput END) AS V1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN version = 'DEF' THEN throughput END) AS V2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN version = 'GHI' THEN throughput END) AS V3
FROM
  results
GROUP BY
  test
ORDER BY
  test;
```

how can i create the max rows as the number of the version and name it according to the version (instead of ABC, DEF...)

| test | version | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | ABC | 10 |
|  | DEF | 20 |
|  | GHI | 30 |
| Test2 | ABC | 40 |
|  | DEF | 50 |
|  | GHI | 60 |

The end goal is to present the data in Grafana similar to this -
[Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3TgJ.png)

while x-axis is all the tests name, and y-axis is the result to each version.

Comment: Here you can see my purpose (with data) - 
------------------------------------
| Test1     | V1      | 10         |
|                | V2      | 15         |
|                | V3      | 20         |
| Test2     | V1      | 20         |
|                | V2      | 18         |
| Test3     | V1      | 50         |
|                | V2      | 65         |
|                | V3      | 70         |
------------------------------------

the version can get change on daily bases.

Comment: Hi. Please add sample data using a `dbfiddle` script https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: done with example.

Comment: Unfortunately, your query doesn't work. Could you fix it? What do you want to get as a result?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your idea correctly, you want to get max value per test.

**The output:**

```
 test  | version | results 
-------+---------+---------
 Test1 | ABC     |      70
 Test1 | DEF     |      80
 Test1 | GHI     |      90
 Test2 | ABC     |     100
 Test2 | DEF     |     110
 Test2 | GHI     |     120
(6 rows)
```

**The query:**

```
with ranked_results as (
      select test, 
             version, 
             results,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test, version ORDER BY results DESC) as max_result_row_number
                    from results)
select test, version, results
from ranked_results
where max_result_row_number = 1;
```

First, with the help of `ROW_NUMBER()` window function we number the rows grouping them by `test` and `version` columns and ordering by `results` in descending order.
Then select rows with the condition `max_result_row_number = 1`.

Here is the [dbfiddle link](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3z86fa5fy).

Comment: No exactly, each test run with multiple versions, for example, Test1 ran with versions ABC, DEF, GHI, i want to get the max results for each version for each test in my db.

Comment: @Elad thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer, and added partitioning by version as well. Please look at the `dbfiddle` link, I've added some test data as well.

Comment: this is defiantly does the job, one more question pls, is it possible to present just 1 time the test name ?

Comment: @Elad please provide an example of the expected result.

Comment: @Elad yeah, actually, my answer format corresponds to yours. I don't understand what you mean 'is it possible to present just 1 time the test name'.

Comment: i tried to make it clearer in the original post.

Comment: @Elad I don't know why you need this exact output format. SQL is not the best tool to do so. Maybe MS Excel can be more suitable.

Comment: @Elad if my answer helped you please vote for it or accept it. Thank you.